# AngularJS binding to Bootstrap Popover attribute

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to dynamically populate the `data-title` and the `data-content` of a Bootstrap popover from a JSON create in an AngularJS controller.

Controller Snippet:

```
$scope.popoverContent = {name: {title: "title", content: "content"}}
```

HTML Snippet:

```
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"
          aria-hidden="true"
          data-toggle="popover"
          data-trigger="hover"
          data-title="{{popoverContent.name.title}}"
          data-placement="right"
          data-content="{{popoverContent.name.content}}">
        </span>
```

I'm getting the exact text between the double quotes in the HTML page, `{{popoverContent.name.title}}`.

I've tried with `ng-attr-data-title="{{popoverContent.name.title}}"` but in this case, the title does not get displayed at all.
Other variables set in the controller are getting displayed properly in the HTML page.

Is is possible to implement something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this code**

```js
var demo = angular.module('demo', []);
demo.controller('loadData', function($scope){
   $scope.uploadData = function() {
    $scope.popoverContent = {name: {title: "title", content: "content"}};
   };
});
demo.directive("popUps",function(){
 return {
   restrict:'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: false,
    template:'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-title="{{popoverContent.name.title}}" data-placement="right" data-content="{{popoverContent.name.content}}">data-title:{{popoverContent.name.title}}</br>data-content:{{popoverContent.name.content}}</span>'
  };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='demo'>
 <div ng-controller='loadData'>
   <button ng-click='uploadData($event)' >show</button>
    <div>
      <pop-ups></pop-ups>
    </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```